# Collasping float gallery

Tags: css, css-float, gallery

My gallery page is not allowing me to add a footer at the bottom of the page or create empty space.

I am using **border-box : box-sizing** 
**AND** self-clearing floats.
I have also tried creating a empty div with a clearfix.

```css
 /* self-clearing floats*/
 .work:after,
 .section:after {
   content: ".";
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
   visibility: hidden;
 }
 *,
 *:before,
 *:after {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .work {
   height: 550px;
   margin-bottom: 40px;
 }
 .work .col {
   float: left;
   width: 49%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 .work .col:first-child {
   margin-right: 2%;
 }
 .work .col > div {
   top: 0;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-bottom: 4%;
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
 }
 .work .col > .lrg {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 .work .col > .sm {
   margin-right: 4%;
   float: left;
   width: 48%;
   height: 48%
 }
 .work .col > .sm.last {
   margin-right: 0;
 }
 .work img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: block;
 }
 .footer {
   height: 100px;
   clear: both;
 }
```

```html
<section class="work">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="lrg">
      <img src="./gnomes14.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="sm">
      <img src="./gnomes2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="sm last">
      <img src="./gnomes3.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end.col-->
  <div class="col">
    <div class="sm">
      <img src="./gnomes10.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="sm last">
      <img src="./gnomes11.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="lrg">
      <img src="./gnomes8.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end.col-->
</section>
<div class="footer">
  <p>help</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this issue happened because section which has class "work", has 550px for its height but its children has more that 550px height.

now footer tag is under of section tag and children of section is over of that and you can not see footer.

delete children of section.work and set background for that and footer and see those tags and after that set new tags on section.work for preventing these issues.

Comment: Thank you, Majid Abbasi. This helped me understand what was going on.  I ended up fixing it with adding .work .col {height:auto;}, instead of height:100% which took the whole page.